# Automatically generate product sort number

Tags: php, opencart-3, ocmod

Thanks for looking at my question.

I'm not a dev so please be patience

I have source this code on github but it's not longer maintened...
Testing this ocmod on my testing installation in Opencart 3.0.3.6 and 3.0.3.8

This xml file will automatically add a product sort order number in the DB if the product have 0 and it will do it from 5000 in reverse 4999...1....(-50000 - infinity )

I need to do it the opposite and the correct way (for me) from 1 to N

Thanks for your collaboration,

```
<file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[ $data['sort_order'] = $this->request->post['sort_order']; ]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[ } elseif ((!empty($product_info)) && ($product_info['sort_order'] == 0)) {
                $data['sort_order'] = ( 5000 - $this->request->get['product_id'] );]]></add>
        </operation>
    <!-- Automatic Product Sort Number -->
            <operation>
                <search><![CDATA[ $data['sort_order'] = 1; ]]></search>
                <add position=" replace"><![CDATA[ $data['sort_order'] = 0;]]></add>
            </operation>
        </file>
```

File [admin/controller/catalog/product.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/4a8ed58da9f83a4476384f50c8aa5a762b427946/upload/admin/controller/catalog/product.php)

File [admin/model/catalog/product.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/4a8ed58da9f83a4476384f50c8aa5a762b427946/upload/admin/model/catalog/product.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with opencart, so I'll give you my guesses

Firstly, try if you can change this "after" for "before"

```
<add position="after">
```

I'm really just curious if it works :D

My second guess would be to just switch

```
    $data['sort_order'] = ( 5000 - $this->request->get['product_id'] );]]></add> // this line for
    $data['sort_order'] = ( 0 + $this->request->get['product_id']  );]]></add> // something like this
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your quick reply, the first line doesn't work as expected so it should remains ```"after"```` the second line of code ```` 0 +```` worked.
But upon checking the DB Table column sort_order I noticed it remains '0' as a value eventhough visually on the frontend show the product ID number mirrored into the sort_number field :S - 
If I Type manually the sort order this will actually be written in the DB as expected, so it seems this code is not doing what I need :( and I cannot use AI in the DB.Table because product_ID already has it.
Any other suggestion?
I edited the q